# Lattice description of matroid duality

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory, duality, matroid-theory

Apologies for this very basic question in matroid theory, but I could not find anything about it online after a bit of searching.

There is a well-known bijective correspondence ("cryptomorphism") between [matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) and [geometric lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_lattice). Duality for matroids is easy to describe: the bases of the dual matroid $M^*$ are the complements of the bases of $M$.

**Question**: Is there a "nice" lattice-theoretic description of what matroid duality means for geometric lattices?

Notice that matroid duality does *not* correspond to order duality ([as the Wikipedia page on geometric lattices notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_lattice#Duality)). Indeed, the order dual of a geometric lattice will not in general be a geometric lattice.

I've found some discussion of "adjoints" for geometric lattices, a concept which seems not directly related to my question here, but maybe I'm missing something. Of course it's also possible that the reason I can't find any source giving a simple lattice description of matroid duality is because there isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that there is no really nice characterization of the type you are looking for. There is some discussion of the matter in Section 3 of Chapter 3 of Welsh's book, *Matroid Theory*. He points out that geometric lattices are not quite equivalent to matroids; they're essentially equivalent to *simple* matroids. And one snag is that the dual of a simple matroid need not be simple.

In the exercises, Welsh poses the following open question:

> Given two geometric lattices $\mathscr{L}_1,\mathscr{L}_2$, is there any way of recognizing the fact that their associated simple matroids $M(\mathscr{L}_1), M(\mathscr{L}_2)$ are dual apart from the obvious rather tedious exhaustive method of testing whether $M(\mathscr{L}_1) \simeq M(\mathscr{L}_2)^*$?

The abstract of Hua Mao's paper [A Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Two Associated Simple Matroids to be Dual](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1005386708000503) (*Algebra Colloquium* 15 (2008), 511–516) says:

> Let $\mathscr{L}_1$ and $\mathscr{L}_2$ be finite geometric lattices, and $M(\mathscr{L}_1)$ and $M(\mathscr{L}_2)$ be their associated matroids. This paper gives a necessary and sufficient condition for $M(\mathscr{L}_1)$ and $M(\mathscr{L}_2)^*$ (the dual matroid of $M(\mathscr{L}_2)$) to be isomorphic, which is actually an affirmative answer to a question of Welsh.

I suspect that the necessary and sufficient condition is still not the "nice" characterization you're hoping for, but I haven't read the paper.

Comment: Thanks, Timothy! This looks like strong evidence that there is no simple description. And the "dual of a simple matroid need not be simple" wrinkle is not something I considered either. I'll wait a little longer, in case anyone else wants to chime in, and then accept this answer.